# Cannot load Image from file:// path in Picasso

Tags: android, image, uri, picasso, android-contentresolver

I am trying to load an image into an `ImageView` from gallery using `Picasso`.

**Here's the code**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode!= Activity.RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST: {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                Log.d(DEBGUG_TAG,"Image URI: "+imageUri.toString());


                Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getApplicationContext());
                picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
                picasso.load(imageUri).error(R.drawable.c).into(testImgView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback(){

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d(DEBGUG_TAG,"Success loading image from uri:PICASSO");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Log.d(DEBGUG_TAG,"Cannot load image");
                    }
                });
```

The problem is while selecting an Image from Gallery it returns a file path

`D/debug: Image URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170126_211524.jpg`

Which doesn't seems to work with Picasso as returns error and logs `D/debug: Cannot load image` in error method.

However choosing the same image from another app which returns `Uri` like :
`D/debug: Image URI: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F90455/ORIGINAL/NONE/1757236944` is successful.

Any way to load image from file path?

Comment: In which sdk version your app is running ? Please check the logcat if you are getting `FileUriExposedException`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont use file:// just use it like this file:

```
 Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            if (data.toString().contains("content:")) {
                imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(targetUri);
            } else if (data.toString().contains("file:")) {
                imagePath = targetUri.getPath();
            } else {
                imagePath = null;
            }

 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null,
                null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting file using `File file = new File(String.value(uri));`, it worked when I changed it to `File file = new File(uri.getPath());`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **ImageView**'s built-in method **setImageURI** for local files

```
testImgView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageUri));
```

Comment: Nope, Same issue, Guess it's not about picasso :P